# Showing 2 data(y) in angular nvd3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, charts, nvd3.js

in my nvd3 config json :

```
x: function(d){ return d.date; },
y: function(d){ return d.failed; },
```

and my JSON is,

```
vm.data7 = [{
      values: [
        {
          'date' : '2016-04-01',
          'fail': 2,
          'success':5
        },
        {
          'date' : '2016-04-02',
          'fail': 2,
          'success':5
        }
           ]
        }]
```

this code will show failed value by date, but i want to show 2 values in single graph (failed and success).

Answer (score 0):

I move from nvd3-charts to n3-charts, and my problem is solve because my JSON structure supported nativelly in n3-charts documentation without pain to re-mapping my JSON. May, i can't solve in nvd3-charts but it can solve in n3-charts as i need, thanks :)

n3-charts data variable like :

```
        {
          dataset: "dataset",
          key: 'fail',
          type: ['line', 'dot', 'area'],
          label: 'Two',
          color: "rgb(200, 96, 69)",
          interpolation: {mode: 'cardinal', tension: 0.7}
        },
        {
          dataset: "dataset",
          key: 'success',
          type: ['line', 'dot', 'area'],
          label: 'Three',
          color: "rgb(119, 48, 131)",
          interpolation: {mode: 'cardinal', tension: 0.7}
        }
```